# Shortcut to google selected text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pdf, mate-desktop, evince

Is there a way to customize evince to search on Google a selected phrase? Like in Firefox where I select a text and right-click--> "Search Google for ..."

If evince isn't customizable, is there any other pdf reader that can do that (and how)?

I'm on Linux Mint - mate desktop (if that matters).

**UPDATE:**
Since firefox seems to be buggy, answers with different mainstream web browsers (chrome, opera etc) are accepted.

**UPDATE 2:**

I found out that

`firefox -remote "openURL(http://www.google.com/search?q=$(xsel), new-tab)"`

works **in terminal**.

I tried to use it in keyboard shortcuts (linux Mint with Mate) and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You could configure `xbindkeys` to do a `firefox "$(xsel)"` upon a key or mouse button press combination. Then that'd work from any application.

Comment: @Braiam: won't that open a firefox instance every time?

Comment: I suppose you wanted to ping @StéphaneChazelas instead

Comment: Yes, indeed I did.

Comment: Recent firefox releases try to contact an already running firefox by default (and don't support running two instances on the same profile).

Comment: I tried to run firefox and it starts a new instance every time (even with -new-tab) and in addition to that I get this message from the terminal: `(process:7304): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By combining:

- Stéphane Chazelas comment
- this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166223/open-firefox-new-tab-in-same-window-through-terminal
- `sh` command cause it wouldn't work otherwise

I got it to work by adding to keyboard shortcuts (**not** `xbindkeys`).

So all the steps are:

`Control center` --> scroll down to `Keyboard Shortcuts` --> Press `Add` and give a name (e.g. "Google it!" and the command:

`sh -c 'firefox -remote "openURL(http://www.google.com/search?q=$(xsel),new-tab)"'`

Don't forget to assign the key combination for activating the shortcut!

**One problem I found out is that if the search string ends with `)` the shortcut won't work.**

**Update:**

@John1024 solved the problem mentioned:
[Escape closing parentheses from URL with firefox -remote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148850/escape-closing-parentheses-from-xsel)

Comment: also with `xclip` : http://askubuntu.com/a/222340/47206

Comment: If this doesn't work, try assigning the command `sh -c 'firefox --new-tab http://www.google.com/search?q="$(xsel)"'` (you may have to `sudo apt install xsel`).