# Escape closing parentheses from URL with firefox -remote

Tags: shell, firefox, url

I have this command (for detailed info see [Shortcut to google selected text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148768/shortcut-to-google-selected-text)):

`sh -c 'firefox -remote "openURL(http://www.google.com/search?q=$(xsel),new-tab)"'`

But when I select a text which ends with `)` it parses it as a closing parenthesis.

Is there a workaround this? (like escaping it somehow?)

Comment: Does this not work? `sh -c 'firefox -remote "openURL(http://www.google.com/search?q='"$(xsel)"',new-tab)"'`

Comment: No, I get not parsable if the string ends with `)` . John1024's solution escapes the characters and it works because firefox actually wants URL encoding (it's a win-win situation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do URL encoding on the string returned by `xsel`.  [Using python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53770/how-can-i-encode-and-decode-percent-encoded-strings-on-the-command-line):

```
sh -c 'firefox -remote "openURL(http://www.google.com/search?q=$(python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(sys.argv[1])" "$(xsel)"),new-tab)"'
```

[Using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script):

```
sh -c 'firefox -remote "openURL(http://www.google.com/search?q=$(perl -MURI::Escape -e '\''print uri_escape($ARGV[0]);'\'' "$(xsel)"),new-tab)"'
```

#### Explanation

Observe what happens when we ask `firefox` to perform a google search on `foo()`:

```
$ firefox -remote 'openURL(http://www.google.com/search?q=Foo(),new-tab)'
Error: Failed to send command: 500 command not parseable
```

To make it "parseable," we need to URL-encode the characters.  For example, here is what `Foo()` looks like when encoded:

```
$ python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(sys.argv[1])"  "Foo()"
Foo%28%29
```

Comment: Both work! Let me get this straight: they work cause they translate symbols like `)` into `&#41` and terminal command won't get corrupted?

Comment: @user2692669 Yes.  `firefox -remove` option expects an internet-safe URL.  So, the parens need to be removed before `firefox` sees them.

Comment: `-remove` or `-remote`? Either-way I get what you want to say. thanks.

Comment: @user2692669 Yes, that was a typo.  Sorry.